# Javascript - Why is Ramda over function not working here?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I'm trying to fill an object with another using the keys as reference.

```
// Object with actual information
{
  'key1.key2.key3': {},
  'key1.key4': {},
}

// Desired Shape

{
   'key1': {
     'key2': {
       'key3': {
       },
     },
     'key4': {
     },
}
```

Using the [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) library this should be a piece of cake, meanwhile, I'm successfully filling an accumulator with the desired shape, I encountered this is not behaving the way I'm expecting.

```
const fillShapeWithParsed = shape =>
R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.reduce(
    (accumulator, [shapeKey, complexValue]) => {
      return R.over(
        R.lensPath(shapeKey.split('.').filter(key => key !== '')),
        R.merge(complexValue),
        accumulator
      );
    },
    shape
  )
);
```

The output on the code above is: If the value of the reference key in the object with info is an array of objects, the accumulator receives the value transformed into nested objects with indexes as keys.

```
// Object with information
{
  'key1.key2.key3': [
    {},
    {},
    {},
  ],
}

// Desired Shape

{
   'key1': {
     'key2': {
       'key3': {
         '0': {},
         '1': {},
         '2': {},
       },
     },
   },
}
```

At this point I know this is done by the [R.merge()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge) func...

So I changed it with [R.clone()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone), and it thrown me an error on how the parameter is not a function.

Besides the fact now the merge function is deprecated I want to replace it to something that helps me on not transforming the **complexValue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not that far off actually. All you're missing I think, is checking whether `complexValue` is an array. If it is, just return it as is (`R.always`) otherwise merge it with `accumulator`.

Also I've assigned `R.pipe` directly to `fillShapeWithParsed`

```js
const input = {
  'key1.key2.key3': {},
  'key1.key4': {},
  'key1.key4.key5': [
    {},
    {},
    {},
  ],
};

const fillShapeWithParsed = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.reduce(
    (accumulator, [shapeKey, complexValue]) => {
      return R.over(
        R.lensPath(shapeKey.split('.').filter(key => key !== '')),
        R.is(Array, complexValue) ? R.always(complexValue) : R.merge(complexValue),
        accumulator
      );
    }, {})
);

console.log(

  fillShapeWithParsed(input)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @BenjamínVázquez I have updated my answer based on your original attempt